# Input on OOPHP database connection script

Tags: php, database, oop, mysqli

I'm learning OOPHP and i just wanted to ask some input from the experienced scripters. This script does work but if i learn it right from the start its better.

This is my connect.php

```
<?php
include ("classes/mysql.class.php");

$mysql = new Connect(); 
$mysql->mysql_Connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'test');?>
```

And this is my mysql_class.php

```
<?php
class Connect {
    var $serverhost, $username, $password, $db_name;

    public function mysql_Connect($host, $user, $pass, $db) {
        $this->serverhost = $host;
        $this->username = $user;
        $this->password = $pass;
        $this->db_name = $db;

        @mysql_connect($this->serverhost, $this->username, $this->password) or die("Kan geen verbinding maken met de database!");
        @mysql_select_db($this->db_name) or die("Kan geen verbinding maken met de geselecteerde database naam");
    }
}?>
```

Any comments are welkom ofcourse!

Comment: Connect is an odd name for your class, as it is a very broad term. The name should make it clear that there is a database connection being made, possibly even a MySQL connection.
You should look into Exceptions, and use them instead of die.

Comment: Perhaps not entirely your question, as that is on how to properly do OO, but PHP has a PDO extension which is more secure then the default mysql. You should look into that too.

Comment: Like the answers below i really appriciate any input, like i said im new to this so im very gratefull for any advice :). thanks

Answer (score 2):

My first piece of advice would be to not reinvent the wheel, PHP already provides a few built in database interface object classes such as PDO, or the class version of the MySQLi extension.

I would also suggest that you don't ever use @ to suppress error messages, as it will come back to haunt you later if you need to debug a script, and it also has a negative impact on script performance.

As far as your approach to OOP goes your class is fairly minimal so there's not much to comment on yet.  I would suggest that you don't use var to declare your class properties, but use public, protected or private instead to set the appropriate visibility. The var keyword is a throwback to PHP 4 and will probably be removed eventually.  Also, it's an alias to public. As a general rule of thumb, you don't want public properties, you want to make them protected or private and implement getters and setters to give other classes access.  The reason for this is if you have public properties there's nothing stopping another piexe of code from screwing up your object's internal state.  Encapsulation and data hiding are important concepts in OOP, so you might want to look into them.

Answer (score 1):

The use of @ to suppress errors is not a really good practice.
Also the use of die in a class is also a really bad practice (it makes the code not testable with phpunit), you should use Exceptions instead

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

PHP already have some class for managing database this way.

Since your class is really simple, why not use

Mysqli class
http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php

PDO Wich I recommend:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php

To manage your database connection. If you want added fonctionality you could subclass PDO or Mysqli.

Comment: Oh, good point, I hadn't even noticed the die() call.  I would add though, that to me exceptions tend to get overused in PHP.  Whilst I think there's times where an exception is the right way to handle things, they should be reserved for exceptional circumstances.  Most reasonable special cases can be handled with normal program flow control constructs